# Error trying to installing JDK8 U11 OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite

Today was the release of Oracle JDK8 U11.

When I try to install the .pkg in OSX yosemite 10.10 I get this error and can't continue.

[image: problem]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The OSX version is stored in /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist

[image]

We can temporary change the OSX version before installing de package.

1. Change OSX version 10.10 to 10.9:

   `sudo sed -i '' 's/>10.10</>10.9</' /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`
2. Install Java and don't forget to change your JAVA_HOME to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk
3. Restore OSX version

   `sudo sed -i '' 's/>10.9</>10.10</' /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`

Comment: I tried this and it worked flawlessly. Should be marked as correct.

Comment: Use the 8u20 version.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the Java 8 package installer which was addressed in the u20 early access release. If you are feeling brave, it is available at https://jdk8.java.net/download.html.