# You cannot use this application with this Mac OS version

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-yosemite

My Mac OS X version is 10.10.1 Yosemite. I wanted to install Java 7 on my Mac. So when I try to install it says "you need Mac OS X version 10.7.3 and later". So I found the following from the web to solve this issue:

[Error trying to installing JDK8 U11 OSX 10.10 Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787530/error-trying-to-installing-jdk8-u11-osx-10-10-yosemite)

> Solution to solve this
>
> We can temporary change the OSX version before installing de package.
>
> Change OSX version 10.10.1 to 10.9:

```
sudo sed -i '' 's/>10.10</>10.9</'/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

> Install Java and don't forget to change your JAVA_HOME to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk
>
> Restore OSX version

```
sudo sed -i '' 's/>10.9</>10.10.1</'/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

So my issue was solved when I tried this (please click on the link if you are not able to understand my Terminal commands). Everything was working fine and I have installed Java 7 also.

After a day when I opened my computer again, all my applications in were locked. I can not open any application even Terminal. It says "You have OS X 10.9. This application requires 10.0 or later". Now I can't open Terminal to change OS version again. Please help me to change OS version again to unlock all my applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you messed up when restoring the OS version. Boot up in single user mode and manually edit `SystemVersion.plist`, then reboot.

1. Boot in single user mode (hold down <kbd>s</kbd> during boot)
2. Make file system readable:

   `/sbin/mount -wu /`
3. Go the `/System/Library/CoreServices` directory:

   `cd /System/Library/CoreServices`
4. Edit `SystemVersion.plist`

   `nano SystemVersion.plist`
5. Change the version strings (note that there may be two of these in the .plist), e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>ProductBuildVersion</key>
        <string>14E46</string>
        <key>ProductCopyright</key>
        <string>1983-2015 Apple Inc.</string>
        <key>ProductName</key>
        <string>Mac OS X</string>
        <key>ProductUserVisibleVersion</key>
        <string>10.10.4</string>                // <<<
        <key>ProductVersion</key>
        <string>10.10.4</string>                // <<<
</dict>
</plist>
```

6. Save and exit (<kbd>Control-O</kbd><kbd>Control-X</kbd>)
7. Reboot:

   `shutdown -r now`

Comment: Hi Paul I just followed this link to go single user mode https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201573

Comment: But I can see some black screen with some commands.. what I should do now ?

Comment: cd to /System/Library/CoreServices and edit SystemVersion.plist (use whichever editor you are familiar with, e.g.vi or nano)

Comment: Hi paul I am not sure how to open SystemVersion.plist file in sinlge user mode. I tried following code "cd to /System/Library/CoreServices" then "open SystemVersion.plist" but When I try this, It says "No application knows how to open /System/Library/CoreServices and edit SystemVersion.plist"

Comment: Hi Paul I did Edit successfully with nano editor. But when I try save It says "[Error writing SystemVersion.plist:Read only permission]" . Please help me to solve this

Comment: Check the permissions on `SystemVersion.plist` - you may need to `chmod +w SystemVersion.plist` to make it writeable - make a backup copy of this file first though, in case you mess up the edit.

Comment: Paul I tried this , it says "Unable to change file mode on SystemVersion.plist": read only file system

Comment: Oh - you didn't make the file system readable after you booted in single user mode - you need to `/sbin/mount -wu /`

Comment: Paul you saved my day.. Million thanks.. I will accept it as a right answer.. I hope I will help some others also..Thanks again

Comment: Great - glad it helped - I've put all the steps into the answer now, in case anyone else has the same problem in future.